# How to use shared variable among parallel process and increment the counter

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, dask, ray

I am trying to increment a counter variable which maintains the total operation count and should be shared among parallel processes to increment it and for that the solution I got is "Actor" in Ray, but it's also not working. The value of `a` is not getting incremented, it just increments by 1 and stays same.

It seems still each process is creating its own copy of the Counter object. How can I do the same with object oriented approach only?

The same approach is working when I am using Python lib multiprocessing `multiprocessing.Pool().apply_async(A.task1,callback=self.task2())`.
How can I do the same in Ray, or if it is possible in Dask?

```py
import ray, time

@ray.remote
class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

    def inc_a(self):
        self.a +=1
    
    def get_a(self):
        return self.a

class A:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.b = 0

    def dotask(self):
        for _ in range(10):
            # print(f"Before Counter(a: {ray.get(c_obj.a.remote())}, b: {self.b})")
            c_obj = Counter.remote()
            A.task1.remote(self, c_obj)
            self.b += 1
            # print(f"After Counter(a: {ray.get(c_obj.a.remote())}, b: {self.b})")
        
    @staticmethod
    @ray.remote
    def task1(self, c_obj):
        time.sleep(20)
        self.task2(c_obj)
    
    def task2(self, c_obj):
        c_obj.inc_a.remote()
        print(f"After Inc (a: {ray.get(c_obj.a.remote())}, b: {self.b})")
```

Current output:

```
(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(1,9)
```

Expected output:

```
(1,0),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,4),(6,5),(7,6),(8,7),(9,8),(10,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Replacement for `apply_async()`

If you only wanted to run a batch of tasks:

```py
@ray.remote
def square(x):
    return x * x

futures = [square.remote(i) for i in range(4)]

print(ray.get(futures))
# -> [0, 1, 4, 9]
```

This is the [ray-core walkthrough](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/walkthrough.html#running-a-task) example.

### Issue with `Counter` instances

You are creating 10 different `Counter` instances (actors) by calling `Counter.remote()` 10 times. Try moving `c_obj = Counter.remote()` outside of the `for` loop, so you pass the same actor to each task.

### Serialization of `class A`

An additional issue is the use of `@staticmethod` here:

```py
class A:
    @staticmethod
    @ray.remote
    def task1(self, c_obj):
```

A *static* method doesn't get a special `self` argument, so `self` is just a normal argument here. Because this is also *remote* method that may be executed on another node, all of its arguments are serialized before calling it, including `self`.

So, every time you call it with `A.task1.remote(self, c_obj)`, the current state of the instance `self` (class A) get serialized and transmitted to the remote worker. This is probably not what you intended.

Comment: Thank you for the solution it's now having same copy of the object but order of execution is not same.. The value of "a" is not ordered like shown in the expected output.. Is it possible to make it ordered like it's working for  pool. Apply-async. I can set ray.get() while calling A.task1.remote() but this will slow the process.. While in apply_async it's working fast.

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is now. Did you really want a shared state/counter? Or was that just so you could use it to manually implement a replacement for `apply_async()`?

Comment: current output is (4,0), (2,1) (7,2) (1,3) (5,4) (9,5) (6,6) (3,7) (0,8) (8,9)  and expected is (1,0),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,4),(6,5),(7,6),(8,7),(9,8),(10,9)

Comment: Your expected output would mean that the tasks are not running in parallel. You are calling the print method from the task. The counter shows the total operation count (at the moment of print).

Comment: I've extended my answer, but I'm afraid I still don't fully understand why you want that output. (To solve some problem? If so, maybe describe that problem in a new question.)

Comment: Thank you maxy for the detailed response.